# setInterval function only calling half

Tags: javascript

Why does my Interval not call the function `dauerrotieren()`?
It appends the string to the html div, so the `Interval` is working.

```
var i = 180;

function dauerrotieren(){
    $("#bannerrotater").css({"transform":"rotateX(" + i + "deg)"});
    i += 180;
    alert(1);
}
var run = setInterval('$("#test").append("1231312"); dauerrotieren()', 1000);
```

Comment: any error in console??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetInterval method first argument should function so try this one.

```
var run = setInterval(function(){
 $("#test").append("1231312"); 
dauerrotieren();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide a function instead of a `String` as the first argument to the function:

```
var run = setInterval(function(){
    $("#test").append("1231312"); 
    dauerrotieren();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a **closure**, passing thereby a **function** and not a **string** to *setInterval*.
This enables a more correct syntax, with the bonus that it is:

- easier to undersant
- highlightable in its syntax
- reusable

So do like:

```
var run = setInterval(function(){
   $("#test").append("1231312"); 
  dauerrotieren();
}, 1000);
```

or maybe:

```
function doSomething() {
   $("#test").append("1231312"); 
   dauerrotieren();
}
var run = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```